# Approximating Volatility Skew From historic returns?

Tags: options, volatility, volatility-skew

I was wondering if someone could help me with something. I've been reading more about equity options, and I'm struggling with skew. Conceptually I understand why it exists, what I'm struggling with is how to put a number to it. At-the-money volatility is a straightforward concept by looking at historical moves, but how would I try to approximate skew form this?

Let's say I have a stock with these following returns for some period of time, and let's further stipulate that we expect this pattern of returns to be a reasonable approximation for the future.

[image]

I just made up a series of stock prices, and calculated an estimate of historic volatility. I believe I did the steps, correctly I took the natural log of the (T1/T0) and found the stnadard deviation of it and annualized it.

Now I have an estimate of at the money volatility. But how would I go about pricing an option with more skew based on this data? Is there any resource that anyone could point me to that discusses this? Most books just discuss historical volatility, and don't really get into details about how to model skew based on historic returns.

Edit:

Now let's say that we are asked to price an 115 Strike option, as well as a 90 strike put, and a 140 strike call.

For the 115 call, I feel like you could use 80% volatility as calculated below. But for the 90 and 140 options, I feel like you could have incorporate some skew, and I'm not sure how to go about that.

I guess fundamentally I'm trying to understand, what skew implies how the returns a stock is expected to have. Volatility tells us how much the market expects a stock to "move".

Comment: Why would you want to use historical returns for ivol skew?

Comment: As @AKdemy pointed out, realized and implied vol are different concepts. What you could do is to calibrate some GARCH model containing a skew parameter (eg GJR-GARCH). Depending on your specific application, this could be a starting point.

Comment: @AKdemy I don't see why not? What you're trying to do this in my hyopthetical scenario is come up with volatilities to price an option. Aren't historical returns a logical place to start? Let's pretend for a moment, there's no market so you can't look at implieds, how would one go about generating volatilities?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I edited my question to see if perhaps that makes more sense. The question is really about trying to price an option without looking at the market's price for guidance. Why aren't historical returns a logical place to start? I mean when you price an option, aren't you implicitly embedding assumptions about how the stock will "move" from t=0 until expiration? It seems like using historical volatility, as a starting point for the volatility you feed black scholes is a reasonable place to start, I'm just trying to extend that to skew.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, Alas: the embedded (volatility) premium in options is sizeable. Empirical volatility is very likely to underestimate option ivol in most times and markets across the skew, with only some empirical similarity in regions of positive returns.

Comment: @Kermittfrog that's a fair point, I've read that implieds tend to be considerably over. But still I think this would at least give you a sense of how much "statistical arbitrage" you could expect right. For instance, if my historical volatility over 4 years is 40%, and the market is suddenly bidding 50%, you could infer that MIGHT be a decent sale. Obviously the market could know something, but still. I'm just looking for a way to measure/think about it. Skew is very very confusing to me, deriving some meaning from it would be very helpful in clearing up the confusion I think

Comment: If there is no market, hence no ivol; one would usually try to find proxy vol surfaces. There are plenty of discussions in existing questions about this; as well as reasons for the skew (Wikipedia is helpful already).

Comment: why this question considered off-topic and closed?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kermittfrog's answer, take a look also at [this](https://www.cap.columbia.edu/files/seasieor/cn2229%40columbia.edu/zhou-paper.pdf) note by Zou and Derman about the `strike adjusted spread', and in particular Appendix B.

Comment: This paper is amazing! Unfortunately my math skills aren't quite up to par, so it's really a struggle for me. But I'm making my through it. slowly I love it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the arguments made against such an idea in the comments to your question, here is what would come to my mind:

1. Calibrate one (or multiple) GARCH model(s) to your daily return data.
2. Generate the return (and hence price) density for your time horizon, say one month forward using the corresponding amount of daily simulations. This step may require some density smoother.
3. Price options directly off the simulated return (hence price) density.
4. Estimate the IVOL (and skew) from the prices under  step 3.

HTH?